# Form Buttons are Drifting

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an application using Visual Studio 2010, C# WinForms .NET 4.0.

The main form is set to be localizable and therefore uses a xxx.resx for its button positions, sizes, etc.

There are a few entries in the resx like this:

```
<data name="btnWorkOrders.Location" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing">
    <value>519, 9</value>
</data>
```

However, when opening the project in Visual Studio and inspecting the "btnWorkOrders", the values in the property section for Location is 519, 8

This is happening for all of my button controls. So, for some reason visual studio is ignoring the values in the resx. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: check the Language property of the Form you're working on. you have to select appropriate culture from there to save control position of that culture in their respctive resx file.

Comment: @Glk.net It's using the (Default) Language. But this is happening when the project is opened. IE I can edit that resx file before I open visual studio and see that the y value is 9. Once I open visual studio, the control value for location.y is not the same (8). If I save the form, it changes the resx file to have the value that Visual Studio opened with (8).

Comment: I tried on my machine, I am not able repro. Try changing the settings. Tools-->Options-->WindowsFormsDesinger-->LayoutMode value

Comment: @Kris I can't reproduce this with any project. Only the large application I am working on. However, I did just reproduce the issue on a co-workers computer also running Visual Studio 2010. This isn't something to do with SnapLines or SnapGrids as it happens without touching any of the elements. I am not physically modifying anything.